# switch with some code written before labels, is it okay?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm wondering if all compilers would silently ignore code before labels in a switch statement, as VS2005 one does.

Here's what I'm after:

```
#define CASE break; case
```

So,

```
switch (i) {
  CASE 0:  print("0");
  CASE 1:  print("1");
}
```

would turn into

```
switch (i) {
  break;
  case 0:  print("0");  break;
  case 1:  print("1");
}
```

From the standard it seems clear that the first "break" (and any other code there if it existed) wouldn't be executed. The standard doesn't deny existence of such code, but I can't be sure about actual compilers.

Comment: Looks a bit dirty of a hack to get breaking switches... Good question though. +1

Comment: Nasty, nasty code! Don't pass it on to me when you are done. (but +1 for the inventiveness)

Comment: Very good implementation of a very bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is implied by §6.4.2¶5 (specifically the ignoring part):

> When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant. If
>   one of the case constants is equal to the value of the condition, control is passed to the statement following
>   the matched case label. If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a default label, control
>   passes to the statement labeled by the default label. If no case matches and if there is no default then
>   none of the statements in the switch is executed.

I don't think your macro is a good idea, however.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would be "unable" to write such code, as all warnings are turned into errors, and an unreachable code warning is likely... and in fact, a quick test on clang++ outputs such a warning.